# Ninja forms datepicker wordpress beforeShowDay

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker, ninja-forms

I'm making a Ninja Forms datepicker where some days have to be blocked. I found a php function in the [NF documentation](http://docs.ninjaforms.com/customer/portal/articles/2045697-faq#faq_datepicker) to add arguments to the datepicker.

Now I want to put in an array with dates and disable the dates in the array.

So here is my function:

```
function nf_datepicker_modify_script( $args ){
//for a list of arguments which can be used here, see the options here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

    $args['minDate'] = 0
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'ninja_forms_forms_display_datepicker_args'
,'nf_datepicker_modify_script' );
```

This works fine. The dates before today are blocked.

Now I want to use: `$args['beforeShowDay']` but I can't get the right array format in.

This is what jQuery tells me: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

This is what I tried:

`$args['beforeShowDay'] = array('25-06-2016' => false, '26-06-2016' => true);`

But that doesn't work.

Can someone help me on my way by telling me in which format my array should be formatted? Then I'll be able to get it to work.

Comment: Hi Sythe, anyway you can help me with the code for disabling past dates for Ninja Forms Datepicker? I tried copy and pasting the code you used but it gives me an error :(

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer. Maybe it's usefull for others as well.

The `beforeShowDate` argument is a callback, so you need to call a function that checks the dates. I solved it by adding a JS function to the datepicker by doing:

`$('.ninja-forms-datepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', myJsFunction);`