# How to write a script to restrict Ninja Form date picker for past dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I have a date picker field in my WordPress Website using the Ninja Forms Plugin. I don't think the plugin gives me the option to restrict past dates. So I want to achieve that the user can not pick any past dates.

I have of course tried to google a solution but I am not really good with javascript/jquery and don't understand how I can achieve this. Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017371/ninja-forms-datepicker-wordpress-beforeshowday

Comment: I tried using that code but unfortunately didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to this by combining a few things I found across the web while trying to solve this problem.

Simply add this code to any page where you have a date picker where you want to restrict past dates. This one also restricts the current day so they have to pick starting tomorrow.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
var customDatePicker = Marionette.Object.extend( {
initialize: function() {

this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'flatpickr' ), 'init', this.modifyDatepicker );
},
modifyDatepicker: function( dateObject, fieldModel ) {
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
dateObject.set("minDate", tomorrow );
}
});


new customDatePicker();
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears Ninja Forms has an advance date picker option I am not familiar with it but here is the [link](https://ninjaforms.com/docs/advanced-datepicker/)

NOW I don't know the exact Ninja Forms syntax but this should jolt your brain to get started.
Other wise you can create a small custom `WP-plugin` using a `add_filter()` and `function` like

```
<?php
  
  add_filter( 'ninja_form_date_limt'  );
  
  function ninja_form_date_limt() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 
        'ninja_form_date_limt', 
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'script.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        false, 
        true 
      );
  }
```

This calls on a `JQuery` or `JavaScript` function in your `theme/js/script.js` file or wherever you keep custom JS Which could will could use something like this.

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
dateObject.pikaday.setMinDate(tomorrow);
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your answer! I am not really good when it comes to custom code, so I am honest that I don't really know where to start to adjust the code you provided to make it fit my needs. If I simply copy and paste it, it gives me an error and my entire site doesn't work anymore

Comment: Yes this code will absolutely produce an error. As the examples above are examples and require other functions or parameters to operate in WordPress. I was hoping maybe it would get you started. But look at the link I provided [Ninja Forms Advance Dates](https://ninjaforms.com/docs/advanced-datepicker) it is a no code solution.